# read large file with XmlTextReader in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextreader

I am reading a large file with XmlTextReader, it takes hours to read and do some processing, during the reading and processing , what will happen if this file is changed or deleted from file server ?

Comment: What have you tried? e.g. Have you tried setting up a small console application that slowly (say one node per second) read in the file, and while it's working try deleting the file, see what happens. Run again this time try modifying the file, see what happens.

Comment: I'm interested in what kind of file size and processing can take hours to complete.

Comment: @Geir somebody yesterday (unrelated I believe) was talking about a 500MB xml file. These things happen, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is *successfully* edited or deleted (i.e. you didn't have it locked for reading), your app will crash (assuming your app thought it had the file open). More likely, though: the other process will not be able to get access to the file to edit/delete it.

If it is the *processing* that takes time, then consider loading the data eagerly. If, however, it is slow due to sheer volume... well, there isn't much can be done about that (assuming the volume * processing-time is the bottleneck; if it is *just* because of the size of the xml file, an alternative format might help). If IO is your bottleneck, you *might* want to try experimenting with compression (either at the file-system level, or explicitly running your xml through gzip when writing) - it *might* (not guaranteed) be that for a spinning platter, reducing the physical reads (trading CPU time decompressing it) speeds things up a little. Probably not the case for SSD or high-performance disks, though.

Comment: just to test it,when it was being used , i deleted the file but there was no exception and app was working properly, i have also tried by modifying the file , but there was no error.It is very Strange...

Comment: this file's size is more than 100 MB, and i read it node by node and than for each node i make some web requests, thats why it takes long time to process.

Comment: @Ishti do you have shadow copy (vss) running, perhaps?

Comment: i dont know,this is a asp.net 2.0 website in IIS, i have not set any specific configuration for this website.

Comment: @Ishti I just tried the same in a console exe; file access was denied (meaning: I couldn't delete it). I think you should show the code you are using to read it...

Comment: here is the code: 
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(url);
reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
while (reader.Read())
{
//some processing
}

Comment: @Ishti is it a URL? or a file path?

Comment: it is a URL , not a path to local file

Comment: @Ishti well then! that is very different! it has probably been loaded and buffered into the web-server that is streaming it, such that it can complete the current request in isolation. That said... streaming a **huge** file and relying on it in transit is risky. I'd save it to %temp%, and read it from there!

Comment: it means it is buffered in webserver,
thank you very much Marc Gravell for your help.